# Would it be theoretically possible to get x,y screen coordinates of caret in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I want to get the caret (text cursor) position inside the active editor.

I know about the `selection.active` property, but it only tells you the line and character position, but I'm interested in the raw x, y screen coordinates.

Is this theoretically possible inside VSCode? Can I convert the `selection.active` into screen space coordinates or maybe somehow hook into raw mouse events?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Getting screen space coordinates is not possible using the VS Code API. The one exception is inside of [webviews](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/extension-guides/webview)

Support for this is also very unlikely to be added to normal editors